# ChromeOptions for converting to mobileweb is not working for RemoteWebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Chromeoptions for converting to mobileweb view is not working when RemoteWebDriver is used for grid. The code snippet is :

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

    Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "iPhone 6");
    Map<String, Object> mobileOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    mobileOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, mobileOptions);
    if (host.equals("grid")) {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", capabilities);
    } else if (host.equals("localhost")) {
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    }
```

When host is used as localhost, the browser opens up in mobile view itself. But the problem arises when we try to run it in grid and pass the host as 'grid'. The browser does not open up in mobile view. Do we have a work around for this?

Also, is it good to automate mobile web using Selenium, or I should move to appium for automating mobile web. I tried to start with selenium as it is much more easy to work with selenium than appium.

- Chrome Version - 70
- Chrome Driver - 2.43
- Selenium - 3.141.5

The grid set up I am using is the official selenium [grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Hub-and-Nodes)